# db.find vs db.aggregation to select nested array Object

Tags: mongodb-query

I'v tried to perform the following  query :

```
db.getCollection('fxh').find({"username": "user1", "pf.acc.accnbr" : 915177},{userid: true, "pf.pfid": true,  "pf.acc.accid":true})
```

and my collection is the following :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5932fd8f381d4c0a7de21942"),
    "userid" : 1496513894,
    "username" : "user1",
    "email" : "user1@gmail.com",
    "fullname" : "User 1",
    "pf" : {
        "acc" : [ 
            {
                "cyc" : [ 
                    {
                        "det" : {
                            "status" : "New",
                            "dcycid" : 1496513941
                        },
                        "status" : "New",
                        "name" : "QPT202017_M1",
                        "cycid" : 1496513940
                    }
                ],
                "status" : "New",
                "accnbr" : 915177,
                "accid" : 1496513939
            }, 
            {
                "cyc" : [ 
                    {
                        "det" : {
                            "status" : "New",
                            "dcycid" : 1496552643
                        },
                        "status" : "New",
                        "name" : "QPT202017_S8",
                        "cycid" : 1496552642
                    }
                ],
                "status" : "New",
                "accnbr" : 73497,
                "accid" : 1496552641
            }
        ],
        "pfid" : 1496513935,
    },
    "lastupdate" : ISODate("2017-06-03T18:18:55.080Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

When I execute the query the result is the following :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5932fd8f381d4c0a7de21942"),
    "userid" : 1496513894,
    "portfolio" : {
        "acc" : [ 
            {
                "accid" : 1496513939
            }, 
            {
                "accid" : 1496552641
            }
        ],
        "pfid" : 1496513935
    }
}
```

And my problem is that I need to see only the concerned accid and the result returns the all accid !.

Any idea how just to return the selected accid of accnbr ?

> NB : I have also tried to add $ sign at the end of my query , it
>   selects the right acc but it returns the all objects or I need just
>   only ONE returned object.

On **6/5/17**

I also used the aggregate command instead of find and it get result by using this :

```
db.getCollection('fxh').aggregate([  { $unwind : "$pf.acc"} , { $match : {"username":"adh1", "pf.acc.accbr": 915177 } }, {$project : {_id:0, accid: "$pf.acc.accid"}}])
```

But could NOT get a lower level result, when I ran this :

```
db.getCollection('fxh').aggregate([  { $unwind : "$pf.acc.cyc"} , { $match : {"username":"adh1", "pf.acc.accbr": 915177, "pf.acc.cyc.name": "QPT202017_M1" } }, {$project : {_id:0, cycid: "$pf.acc.cyc.cycid"}}])
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Try  `db.getCollection('fxh').aggregate([  { $match : {"username":"adh1"} },  { $unwind : "$pf.acc"} , { $match : {"pf.acc.accbr": 915177 } }, { $unwind : "$pf.acc.cyc"},  { $match : {"pf.acc.cyc.name": "QPT202017_M1" } }, {$project : {_id:0, accid: "$pf.acc.accid", cycid: "$pf.acc.cyc.cycid"}}])`

Comment: okay it seems working , thank you, could please just give a little explanation about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation pipeline.

The idea is to `$unwind` one nested level at a time, starting from the outermost to the innermost.

For each nested level unwinding, you can apply the`$match` to limit the documents and continue till you have the desired shape.

You can `$group` it together at the end to get back to the original shape.

```
db.getCollection('fxh').aggregate([ 
{ $match : {"username":"adh1"} }, 
{ $unwind : "$pf.acc"} , 
{ $match : {"pf.acc.accbr": 915177 } }, 
{ $unwind : "$pf.acc.cyc"}, 
{ $match : {"pf.acc.cyc.name": "QPT202017_M1" } }, 
{$project : {_id:0, accid: "$pf.acc.accid", cycid: "$pf.acc.cyc.cycid"}}])
```